# How do I apply an OR condition?

Tags: 8, database

I've got the below code

```
$query = \Drupal::database()
  ->select("excel", "e")->fields("e");
$group = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->condition("grupindex", 1)
  ->condition("grupkodu", NULL);
$query->condition($group);
$excel_products = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM excel WHERE grupkodu = 1 OR grupkodu IS NULL`, I get 1594 records, however the above code gives only 638 records, which means only grupkodu condition is taken into account. What is the proper way to apply OR?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of dabbling, I got the answer. `->condition("grupkodu", NULL);` is not sufficient, it needs to be `->condition("grupkodu", NULL, "IS NULL");`